# SQL - value for the last date

Tags: sql

Sounds easy I guess for some of you guys but can't find the solution due to my poor sql knowledge.

I have a request:

- first 3 columns with `margin` which can be `null`

I want to create a column `Last Application Margin` with the rule:

- if margin is null then last value no null you find.

screenshot here:

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't post images but text. Or show us how we can copy-paste your sample data to sql-fiddle.

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNULL`/`COALESCE` and a subquery:

```
SELECT scope_enum_compete, margin, date_test,
       ISNULL(margin, ( SELECT TOP 1 margin
                        FROM dbo.TableName t2
                        WHERE margin IS NOT NULL
                         AND  t2.date_test < t1.date_test 
                        ORDER BY date_test DESC )) AS  [last applicable margin]
FROM dbo.TableName t1
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. You sure you can use TOP is subquery?

Comment: @rom: at least in sql-server, i think it doesn't work in sybase as [this thread](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1653299-Sybase-Top-N-in-Subquery-equivalent) suggests.

Comment: I confirm, subquery not allowed on sybase IQ

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the Max() and group by

```
SELECT margin, MAX(date_test)
FROM some_table
GROUP BY margin, ope_num_compute;
```

Comment: It will returns 2 lines. 1 with margin 34 and 1 with margin 50. I need 1 line